# BeautifulSoup does not Parse as Expected

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am using BeautifulSoup 4 for crawling a web site and generated a script that works like a charm. But when I changed computers and tried the script on another one, it suddenly started to give out an error. The cause of the error is that I used css search, which is a new capability of BS and valid for the latest versions. The specific search goes like this:

```
soup.findAll(class_="class-name")
```

"class-name" exists in the web page and it is working that I know for sure. The problem is, the new computer somewhat fails to parse the web-page successfully and can not detect any class named "class-name". As you would expect, the search above returns an empty list.

I installed `html5lib` and `lxml`, both together and alone: nothing changed. I made sure BS parse with `lxml` and `html5lib` in two different cases with the following lines:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen("url")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"html5lib")
```

or

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"lxml")
```

And nothing changed again. Search returns an empty list. Please help me on this. I am looking for a to-the-point answer by the way, just help me to make BS create a correct parsing. Please try not to give advices that will require me to change a lot in my script. As I said before, it is working.

Thanks in advance.

---

In the light of comments, I am including a short failing example. By the way, the versions of everything is the same in both computers, except python. The computer on which the script works has pyhton 2.6 and the other one has 2.7. But I do not think this is the reason.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen("www.website.com/some extensions...")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

#Now I need information that is included in a class called any_class. The info's
#html tag is 'i' and I want to extract the text in that tag, for the first appearance
#of any_class on the page

text = soup.findAll(class_="any_class")[0].i.text
```

Now I navigate to command line and run the script.

```
$ ./crawler.py

#Index Error! List out of Index!
```

I hope now everything is clear to you. As you can see, soup.findAll returns an empty list for the class search of "any_class". BS clearly can not find "any_class" that is found barely on the page. I believe strongly that the problem is a parser problem. I guess python insists on using its default "html.parser" instead of lxml and html5lib that I installed. You can also include a short guide in your answer about how I should declare to python that I want to parse with lxml or html5lib for BS.

Comment: Can you give us some sample data that's failing? (Also, do the working and non-working machines have the same versions of python, bs4, etc.? If not, what versions?)

Comment: Adding a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to your question will give us a better idea of what could be the problem (you could even resolve it yourself while building the example, who knows d:).